# showing an inequality regarding expectation of a random variable

Tags: probability, inequality

Suppose $h: \mathbb{R} \to [0, \alpha] $ is bounded and $0 \leq a < \alpha $. Then

$$ P( w : h(X(w)) \geq a ) \geq \frac{ \mathbb{E}(h(X(w)) - a )}{\alpha - a } $$

I was trying to use the fact that $|h| \leq M$ for some $M $ real. and we know $\mathbb{E}( h(X) - a) = \mathbb{E}(h(X)) - a \leq M - a  $. So it would be enough to show that $M - a \leq P( h(X(w)) \geq a ) $. I am stuck here. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}(h(X)-a) &= \mathbb{E}((h(X)-a) 1_{\{h(X)<a\}}) + \mathbb{E}((h(X)-a) 1_{\{h(X) \geq a\}}) \\ &\leq 0 + (\alpha-a) \mathbb{P}(h(X) \geq a). \end{align*}$$